# System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException was unhandled in C#

Tags: c#, async-await

To close window I used Environment.Exit(0);
I got error as follows:

System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
Additional information: A task was canceled.

Is there any way to check any task is still running before I close window?

Thanks in advance.

Joon

Comment: "To close window I used Environment.Exit(0);" not ... Window.Close??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the task, store it somewhere. If you plan to create more than one task, you may need a collection to store them in. For example, you could store it in a ConcurrentBag, which will be safe even if you are creating tasks on multiple threads.

```
static class Globals
{
    static public ConcurrentBag<Task> RunningTasks { get; } = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();
}

//Main code
var task = Task.Run( () => DoSomethingThatTakesALongTime() );
Globals.RunningTasks.Add(task);
```

Then, before you exit, see if any of them are still running. If they are, you can use [Task.Yield](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.yield(v=vs.110).aspx) to surrender control and give them a chance to run.

```
while (Globals.RunningTasks.Any( t => !t.IsCompleted ))
{
    await Task.Yield();
}
Environment.Exit(0);
```

The better solution, though, is to handle the exception, if possible.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way to get all the list of task that is not complete?

Comment: Exception I got here is from external code, which I can't control. Is there any way to suppress it.

Comment: Maybe read again? The code example I provided includes logic that detects tasks that are not yet complete.

Comment: I have been using many tasks and I stored and checked them all. But I couldn't  find any unattended.